# Sketch App + Zeplin, font book with colors?

Tags: sketch-app

After having some trouble with Sketch + Sympli I'm trying to switch to Zeplin. So far, so good. However, I noticed for a lot of font elements Zeplin doesn't show the color. In a photo I found online and from memory of past projects I know it should be possible:

[image: Image by Tutsplus]

But for me all font elements are showing up without colors:

[image]

I am using text styles in Sketch, and in Sketch the text styles show up colored as they should be. When I click the text I can see a color is selected:

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong as far as settings goes? Can Zeplin not handle font styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug caused by an update in Sketch 48 and 48.1.
They have changed something about colors in font styles.

Zeplin is looking to fix this ASAP.
Sympli seems to have the same issue but for only some people.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update Zeplin to the latest version? I had the same issue with my designs. However, it is working after updating Zeplin to the latest version.